# unix test -f command equivalent in powershell?

Tags: unix, powershell

I'm converting unix scripts into powersshell scripts. 
I want to know the **unix test -f equivalent commnad in powershell**.

Unix test -f  equivalent powershell command

Comment: Do you know what the *nix command `test -f` does? Have you tried a Google search for intended functionality and keyword `powershell`?

Answer (score 0):

In powershell we have [test-path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.management.activities.testpath_members%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).